# How do I separate the "Product" select list & "Add to cart" submit form in a node product display?

Tags: theming, commerce

I have a node product display which references 2 different products.

When I use the code below, it prints out both the "product select" form + the "add to cart" submit form. How do I print them out separately?

```
<?php print render($content['field_product_ref']); ?>
```

Alternatively, how do I change the HTML to print this 2 form out? I am looking for a way to theme my product display differently.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that you can't, albeit after several hours of experimenting.

However, you can add a price field (and other fields) to your "add to cart" form by adding a "price" form item element. Follow the instructions here for more details: http://drupal.org/node/1300798#comment-5328550

Tell me if this helps.